# send variable to another if statement

Tags: javascript

I'm struggling with variables, why is this one not defined?

```
function myFunction(){
  if(){
    let mytimer = setInterval(function() {
      alert("hello");
    }, 1000);   
  }
  else if(){}
  else{
    clearTimeout(mytimer);   <--- this is not set
  }

  if(){
    clearTimeout(mytimer); <---  this one is not set aswell.
  }
}
```

I also have it in another if statement a bit under in the same function,  it's not set aswell. What am I missing? I had `var mytimer` first but then I remember let should exist outside the statement right?

Edit: I am unable to put the variable outside my if statement

Comment: It seems you need to change the scope of your variable. Put your variables outside of your if statement

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope

Comment: But if I need to have it inside my if statement?

Comment: You can declare the variable outside the if statement and assign it inside.

Comment: For example I do not wish to alert many things if the statement is not true, but If another thing happens I want it to stop alerting messages

Comment: Please elaborate on what exactly you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: The way your function looks like seems to suggest that `myFunction` is supposed to be called at least *twice*: One time it will create the interval and later it might clear it. That already implies that `mytimer` should be declared *outside* of the function so that it persists across function calls. Is that assumption correct? If not, please elaborate how this code is supposed to work/what you are actually trying to achieve. It seems to be an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Felix clearified for me so I created it outside, thanks for all the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue with scope.

Your variable, `mytimer`, is being declared locally within your `if` statement, meaning it can't be accessed by anything outside of that `if` statement as it doesn't exist there.

You could declare it outside the `if` blocks to start with and then reference it inside them when needed like so:

```
function myFunction(){

  //Declare mytimer here
  let mytimer = 0;

  if(//condition){
    mytimer = setInterval(function() {
      alert("hello");
    }, 1000);   
  } else if(//another condition){
    //do something
  } else{
    clearTimeout(mytimer);   <--- this will now be accessible here
  }

  if(){
    clearTimeout(mytimer); <--- as will this one
  }
}
```

Edit: I see from your edit you've said you can't declare your variable outside your `if` blocks.

As far as I'm aware, it's not possible to access local variables outside of scope in JavaScript; therefore, your only option is most likely to rewrite the program in a way that means you can unfortunately.

Comment: Right idea, but I don't see how that would accomplish anything. OP needs to provide more information.

Answer (score 1):

when you define a variable inside of a block scope like if, it is not accessible from outside of the scope, you can change the scope, write your variable outside of block scope or, you can use var instead of let ...

```
function myFunction(){
  let myTimer= null 
  if(){
     myTimer = setInterval(function() {
      alert("hello");
    }, 1000);   
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi! This is not meant as a discussion forum - please write an answer with `code` as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Universal answer:**
The way you asked the question, your variable/s should be declared outside of the if-else block with some defaulting value. What value it takes inside a truthy condition block is another matter.

**Answer specific to JS:**
Using **var** will set the variable for hoisting outside of the inner if-else scope (if the same var exists it will be overridden with the new value).
However, **let** (which you use in your example) declares that the variable will have to exist only inside the inner if-else scope.

Advices:

1. You should mention the programming language you want to use. Do not force people to guess if you are using some sort of pseudo-code or JS or something else.
2. Give enough code context
3. Learn more about JS Scopes, hoisting and closures:

   - https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/scope-closure-hoisting-in-javascript/
   - https://ui.dev/ultimate-guide-to-execution-contexts-hoisting-scopes-and-closures-in-javascript/

--> both links are providing good examples and context.